# как грамотно обработать NPE в данной ситуации

Tags: java, исключения

Есть презентер, в разных его методах есть вызовы метода `getView()` , который расположен в базовом презентере.

```
protected V getView() {
        return view;
    }
```

Если `view == null` мне удобно просто не выполнить метод и ничего не делать. В ситуации моего одноэкранного приложения это идеально подходит.  Но писать кучу блоков `try/if`  я не хочу. Мне хочется перед попыткой использовать `view` один раз проверить и пресечь дальнейшее выполнение кода.

Если я как нибудь обработаю эту ситуацию внутри метода `getView()` я всё равно должен буду выполнить `return view;`

**UPD** как вижу мой вопрос не понятен. Вот подробности.

```
public class BasePresenter<V extends BaseView> implements MvpPresenter<V> {
    private V view;

    @Override
    public void attachView(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView() {
        view = null;
    }

    protected V getView() {
        return view;
    }  
}
```

Ну и сам презентер:

```
public class MainMenuPresenter<V extends MainView> extends BasePresenter<V>
        implements MainPresenter<V> {

    public void setData(PostModel postModel) {
            ....
            getView().refreshSpinner();
            ....
            getView().refreshAdapterModelDate();
        }


     private void validationOfData(PostModel postModel) {
            if (postModel.getDate() == null) {
                getView().refreshAdapterModelDate();
                getView().showToast("В");
            } else if (!postModel.getDate().equals(currentDate)) {
                getView().refreshAdapterModelDate(); 
                getView().showToast("");
            } else {
                //Если всё в порядке
                setData(postModel);
                dataManager.setDataBase(postModel);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Тут зависит от контекста. Но вы можете и без if/try обойтись, например: `getView() != null && getView().updateListView();`

Comment: Можно использовать Optional, и вызов .getView().ifPresent(...)

Comment: gil9red, не понял ваш ответ. метод getView().updateListView();  не возвращает булево значение.

Comment: Ihar Hulevich, ваш ответ я тоже не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если совсем проверять не хочется, есть такое понятие, как **null object**. Смысл его в том, что вместо null поля сетятся специальным статическим объектом или синглтоном (в целях экономии), который имплементит тот же интерфейс, что и поле, и возвращает (при необходимости) дефолтное значение. В твоем случае это будет что-то вроде

```
MyClass(){ view = NullView.getInstance(); }
protected V getView() {
        return view;
    }
    ...
}
class NullView implements Viewable {
...
    public void updateListView(){ }
...
}
```

Использование такого объекта поможет избавиться от лишних проверок, при этом NPE никогда не произойдет

Comment: Спасибо, не понявшие мой вопрос заминусовали.  Узнал про null object pattern,  это то что нужно в моей ситуации

Comment: @Turalllb Не парься. Тут такое бывает :)